# C# script to convert first line of txt document into a create table statement for SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

So I have grown tired of having to use the **import wizard** to create a table from a new **TXT tab delimited file** every time I get a new text file i have to analyze. Most of what I am doing is rough data analysis, but I grow tired of access SQL and the documents sometimes are large enough that Excel analysis wont cut it. I haven't found a great way to import Data from multiple files into SQL Server quickly. I know of **bulk import**, but from my understanding you need a table already made to use it. My text files are ALWAYS different so i cant just create a generic table and recreate it.

I am writing a C# code that hopefully eventually will take a filepath and take a copy of every text file in the path and cut it down to the first {CR}{LF} in each doc, define my delimiter '\t' ',' '|' etc. , and make a create table statement for every file in the path. I want to do this so I can then do a simple bulk import for each file and be done.

This is what I have so far: Im trying to get it to work on a SINGLE  tab delimited file

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string pathOfFile = textBox2.Text;
        string origFileText = File.ReadAllText(pathOfFile);
        int intIndexofCRLF = origFileText.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine);
        string strIndexfCRLF = intIndexofCRLF.ToString();
        string strJustHeader = origFileText.Substring(0, intIndexofCRLF);
        string[] splitarray = strJustHeader.Split('\t');
        string tablename = textBox3.Text;
        string SQLPart1 = "CREATE TABLE " + tablename + "( ";
        string sqlbody = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < splitarray.Length; i++)
        {
            sqlbody = sqlbody + "[" + splitarray[i] + "] " + "varchar(255), " ;

        }
        string SQLpart2 = sqlbody.Substring(0, sqlbody.Length - 1); 
        string SQLPart3 = ");"
        MessageBox.Show(SQLPart1 + SQLPart2 + SQLPart3);
    }
```

For some reason, my array is messing up when I do this.

My input is D:\newtext.txt

abd abc ans azd

1   2   3   4

My desired output is

CREATE TABLE newtext ( abd varchar(255), abc varchar(255), ans varchar(255), azd varchar(255));

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe you need to do "string SQLpart2 = sqlbody.Substring(0, sqlbody.Length - 2);" instead of "string SQLpart2 = sqlbody.Substring(0, sqlbody.Length - 1); " because you have comma and space appended to  sqlbody in the loop. And use StringBuilder instead of concatenating strings because it's more performance efficient (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306822).

Comment: What are you getting instead of your desired output? One tip: instead of `Environment.NewLine` I'd look for CR (`\r`) or LF ('\n'). There's no guarantee the files will have the proper newline delimiter - whoever created them could have used either or a combination of both.

Comment: StringBuilder is definitely faster, but not so you'd notice. The real time-waster here is using `File.ReadAllText` when you only need the first line of the file. Once you get your string stuff figured out, take a look at [Reading a text file one line at a time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx). The example is only 3-4 lines of code, it's easy to follow, and you'll definitely see a speed boost - especially if the files are large.

Comment: Thanks. BTW the articles you posted helped a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would improve few things in this code :

1. StringBuilders are more efficient than just concatenating strings,
   you should use them
2. Handing both windows ("\r\n") and Unix ("\n") lines ends.
3. Reading only the first line of the file from disk instead of reading all of
   the file to the memory and then get the first line from it

Here an example code that contains those improvements :

```
string tableName = "myTable";
string delimeter = " ";
string line = null;
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead("FilePath"))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    line = sr.ReadLine();
}
string fileHeader = line.Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty);
string[] fileHeaderSegments = fileHeader.Split(new string[] { delimeter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Format("CREATE TABLE {0} (", tableName));
for (int i = 0; i < fileHeaderSegments.Length; i++)
{
    if (i != 0)
    {
        sb.Append(",");
    }
    sb.Append(fileHeaderSegments[i]);
    sb.Append(" varchar(255)");
}
sb.Append(");");
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for all of the help! very helpful